# Azure WebApp and WebJob

Tags: python, csv, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Right now I have a python script that reads a csv file, does some calculation, and then writes that csv back with the results of the calculation, and finally emails the file to the user. This is done on each persons local machine right now. Additionally, we have an azure web app that does a few different calculations and user interactions. Something we want to add to the web app is a little admin page, which allows a user to upload a csv file, enter a few variables into some text boxes, then hit "run". Hitting run will cause the file and the inputs to be passed to an Azure web job which will run the python script.

How can I get the web app to submit the file uploaded as well as the inputs to the web job? In essence I suppose I am going need to figure out how to make the web app communicate with the web job.

Comment: IMO, this conceptual question might be better suited for the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) section of StackExchange.

Comment: @JohnWhite when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

WebJob is not the best match for this, because you're expecting a reply/something back. While you CAN run a WebJob continuously that exposes a REST interface, it's really not a great solution. Consider this instead:

- Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
- Call an API controller on your
  website with the blob URL as it's parameter. The WebSite can now read
  that file and process it and return an answer to your app.

Here are some samples of working with blob storage if you've never done it before:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think there are two solutions for the needs.

1. Online mode. If the csv file size is not big and the calculating process is simple, you can directly calculate the data from the uploaded csv file with few arguments, then write the result to the response.
2. Offline mode. Preprocess the uploading csv file and convert to the other format file with arguments like [`ARFF`](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html), then push it into the [Azure Storage Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage/). The continuous running webjob get the file from the Storage queue and calculate the data part with the arguments part, then write the result to Azure Storage Blob and record the blob path for donwloading.